# Django 1.5 "Page not found" with GET parameters in url

Tags: python, django, url, parameters, get

I have little trouble with Django. It cannot recognise urls with get params like this:

```
http://example.com/login/?next=/me/registrace/
```

I suppose it is due to bad settings, but I dont know where. The same problem is even in administration.

This is what I see on error page:

```
Using the URLconf defined in example.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^imperavi/
    ^login/$ [name='login']
    ^$ [name='index']

The current URL, login/, didn't match any of these.
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib import admin

from example.views import IndexView, LoginView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(_(r'^admin/'), include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(_(r'^imperavi/'), include('imperavi.urls')),
    url(_(r'^login/$'), LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(_(r'^$'), IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

I tried to remove ugettext translations, but it didnt help.

I also tried to remove all my rules and let there just `admin`, but still it doesn't work. I tried admin url:

```
http://example.com/admin/auth/user/?o=-1
```

Comment: Please show your urls.py.

Comment: Doesn't it work with `manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: I run it on Gunicorn + nginx proxy, but I tried `runserver` and it is the same.

Comment: Could you post your views.py in full or at least the LoginView?

Comment: Do you have a custom context processor or a url resolver?

Comment: AndrewS: I believe, it is not problem of views. Because it is even in Django admin.

Comment: Sudipta: yes, I have custom context processor, but when I turn it off, it is the same problem.

Comment: Sudipta: Oh, I tried turn off my custom middleware and now it works. I guess that there is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There is a slash missing in the last url:

> ...
>
> ^$ [name='index']
>
> The current URL, login/, didn't match any of these.

There is it: your rule should be `url(_(r'^/$'), IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, but it didn't help. The problem with `?something` still persists.

Comment: And perhaps it isn't correct, because I can't get to the `http://example.com` url.